# THREE.js freezes after I splice 3dObject from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js

I have a online realtime game I am creating. All of my players and their animation mixers are stored in arrays. Everything works fine until a players leaves the game. When they leave I try splicing them from the player array but every time I do so, the program freezes.

```
var indexer = i;
scene.remove(players[indexer]);
players[indexer].geometry.dispose();
players[indexer].material.dispose();
players.splice(indexer, 1);
interval.splice(indexer, 1);
mixers.splice(indexer, 1);
anim.splice(indexer, 1);
ids.splice(indexer, 1);
```

What is going wrong when I try splicing these arrays?

Comment: When are you splicing?  Is it in the middle of an iteration of some kind?

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: To the first comment, it's in the middle of a for loop,

Comment: To the second comment, I am not getting any errors, it's just freezing on me

Answer (score 0):

It ends up you cannot splice 3dObjects from an array in the middle of a for loop with three.js. So instead I created a function, and called that function with `window.setTimeout()`. Everything now works beautifully.

```
window.setTimeout(RemovePlayer, 10, i);

function RemovePlayer(indexer){
    scene.remove(players[indexer]);
    players[indexer].geometry.dispose();
    players[indexer].geometry = null;
    players[indexer].material.dispose();
    players[indexer].material = null;
    players[indexer].dispose();
    players[indexer] = null;
    players.splice(indexer, 1);
    interval.splice(indexer, 1);
    mixers.splice(indexer, 1);
    anim.splice(indexer, 1);
    ids.splice(indexer, 1);
}
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with THREE.js. Modifying arrays while iterating them is always tricky and has to be well thought out. What is probably happening is you are passing null to scene.remove or something because your iteration logic is broken.